# How to resolve Azure Devops with iOS : Error: Error Domain=com.apple.dt.IDEContainerErrorDomain Code=6

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

```
 Error: Error Domain=com.apple.dt.IDEContainerErrorDomain Code=6Error: Error Domain=com.apple.dt.IDEContainerErrorDomain Code=6 "Cannot open "Docs.docc" as a "Swift Package Folder" because it is already open as a "Folder"." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot open "Docs.docc" as a "Swift Package Folder" because it is already open as a "Folder
```

I was using Azure devops with iOS project , everything went well until this morning. It look like swift-log and SwiftProtoBuf SPM which called inside Firebase SPM cause this error.
I have heard there was a way to resolve this by disable caching in CI system , but i had no idea how to.

Update firebase to 10.3.0
Nothing resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

On our project, we are using MacStudio, also we have removed DerivedData and SPM repositories, which helped us. Also we have added some target to our project and on MacStudio, we manually made an archiving, to generate missing certifications.

1. Remove DerivedData - ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
2. Remove SPM repositories - ~/Library/Caches/org.swift.swiftpm/repositories
3. Manually archive the project
4. Than retry it from Azure.

**Edit**: The pipeline was failing and we tought that it failes, but there was another reason and this steps helped us.